# Writing JQuery to change behavior of TB Megamenu for Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

I'm incredibly new with Javascript and JQuery and I am having problems getting the behavior to work as I would like.  I currently have two dropdown TB MegaMenus on top of my website while it is underneath 980px.  The issue is that since they are separate menus, when you have one open and click to open the second menu, the first one does not close.  I am attempting to have them close the other when they are opened.  They operate by changing their overflow from hidden to visible.  .nav-collapse is the class on both div's that needs to be hidden once the other one is opened.  I understand that we need to change the css to be overflow: hidden, but I'm not doing it properly and am having trouble even after looking up many examples.  Any help would be appreciated.

The DOM looks something like this.

> .l-region > #block-tb-megamenu-main-menu > .block__content > .tb-megamenu-main-menu > .nav-collapse (this is the one that needs the CSS modified to overflow: hidden)

---

> $(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#block-tb-megamenu-main-menu").on('click', '.nav-collapse', function(){
    $('#block-tb-megamenu-menu-connect').find(".nav-collapse").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
});
```

This is the code that performs the function within TB Mega Menu.  Would it be possible just to modify this code?

> attach: function(context) {

```
  $('.tb-megamenu-button').click(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.nav-collapse').height())) {
      $(this).parent().children('.nav-collapse').css({height: 0, overflow: 'hidden'});
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().children('.nav-collapse').css({height: 'auto', overflow: 'visible'});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what I needed to do.  I had to add the first line to the else statement, this closes everything that has a class of .nav-collapse, and then opens the appropriate one.

> attach: function(context) {

```
  $('.tb-megamenu-button').click(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).parent().children('.nav-collapse').height())) {
      $(this).parent().children('.nav-collapse').css({height: 0, overflow: 'hidden'});
    }
    else {
           /*line that I put in to allow for other menus to close when one is clicked.*/
      $('.nav-collapse').css({height: 0, overflow: 'hidden'});
      $(this).parent().children('.nav-collapse').css({height: 'auto', overflow: 'visible'});
    }
  });
```